# Multiplying not working with with gl-matrix.js's function mat4.multiply

Tags: javascript, matrix, gl-matrix

I want to multiply 2 matrices with the gl-matrix.js library [gl matrix mat4](http://glmatrix.net/docs/mat4.html)

The multiplication does work f.e. this :

```
    var testMat = mat4.create();
    mat4.multiply(testMat, this._transformations[0].transformation, this._transformation.transformation);
```

Where `this._transformation[x].transformation` is a matrix.

But it doesnt work when doing this :

```
    mat4.multiply(this._transformations[0].transformation, this._transformations[0].transformation, this._transformation.transformation);
```

Which means the matrix stored in `this._transformations[0]` is still the same after the multiplication.

Has someone an explanation for this or can tell me what i am doing wrong?

Edit : `console.log(mat4.equals(mat4.create(),this._transformations[0].transformation))` returns `true`

Comment: You have not given enough information. There is no reason your calls should not work. Unless the you are multiplying by an identity matrix the out matrix (first argument) should be the product of the next two. You need to show the incorrect result and the original matrix's  content so we have something to go by.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools